# how to scrape dynamic web pages using ui path studio

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-api

I tried web scraping reviews from a website called https://mmb.moneycontrol.com and the reviews posted on this website are loaded dynamically. The amount of reviews scraped are 40 only
i tried changing the "MaxNoOfResults" variable to higher value (300,400...) but the amount of **scraped** reviews remained the same. I even tried assigning a new excel sheet every time I scraped even that did not fetch any different results
can someone please help me increase the **scraped** reviews

Comment: FYI it’s _scraped__ not scrapped

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the reviews are loaded upon scroll down it seems.
The UiPath process is only able to "see" the elements that have been loaded.

I would suggest to use the Send Hotkey activity with "Page Down" key to scroll down the page and force the loading of the elements before doing the **scraping**.

The challenge is going to be to decide when to stop, so you will need to decide on some logic for that (there is no obvious or generic approach to this I am afraid)